# BS4 web scraping is not returning anything

Tags: python

My code:

```
res=requests.get('https://www.flickr.com/photos/')
res.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
linkItem = soup.select('div.photo-list-photo-interaction
a[href^=/photos]')
print(linkItem)
```

is not returning any values. 
After Inspecting element, the photos are inside a `<div class "photo-list-photo-interaction">`. So above `soup.select` should have worked. But it doesn't. Any ideas?

Comment: its href in my original code. I must of removed the "h" by accident. Still not working...

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the actual source you can see:

```
<div  class="view photo-list-view requiredToShowOnServer" style="height: 4578px" data-view-signature="photo-list-view__UA_1__exploreId_2016-09-17__isMobile_false__isOwner_false__photoListConfig_1__photoListLayoutStyle_justified__requiredToShowOnClient_true__requiredToShowOnServer_true__subnavConfig_1"><div  class="view photo-list-photo-view requiredToShowOnServer awake" style="transform: translate(0px, 4px); -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 4px); -ms-transform: translate(0px, 4px); width: 564px; height: 305px; background-image: url(//c6.staticflickr.com/9/8279/29103697453_ca811d0e07_z.jpg)" data-view-signature="photo-list-photo-view__UA_1__contextSuffix_explore-2016-09-17__engagementModelName_photo-lite-models__exploreId_2016-09-17__id_29103697453__interactionViewName_photo-list-photo-interaction-view__isMobile_false__isOwner_false__layoutItem_1__measureAFT_true__model_1__parentContainer_1__parentSignature_photolist-232__photoListLayoutStyle_justified__requiredToShowOnClient_true__requiredToShowOnServer_true__subnavConfig_1">
```

The urls you see in your browsers are dynamically created using css. Insoide the div you can see `background-image: url(//c6.staticflickr.com/9/8279/29103697453_ca811d0e07_z.jpg)` so that is what you need to get.

You can do it using a css selector with a regex:

```
In [1]: import requests
In [2]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    
In [3]: import re
In [4]: url_re = re.compile("url\(//(.*?)\)")

In [5]: res = requests.get('https://www.flickr.com/photos/')

In [6]: soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

In [7]: urls = [url_re.search(d["style"]).group(1) for d in soup.select('div.view.photo-list-view div[style*=url(//]')]

In [8]: print(urls)
[u'c1.staticflickr.com/9/8385/29133157664_856aef9bc3_n.jpg', u'c5.staticflickr.com/9/8212/29128075804_0c166556c5_n.jpg', u'c3.staticflickr.com/9/8070/29138685794_984cf0a7f2.jpg', u'c3.staticflickr.com/9/8084/29465161650_4a1a160928.jpg', u'c5.staticflickr.com/9/8202/29642526492_357d7da694_n.jpg', u'c8.staticflickr.com/9/8164/29769287735_6523928d3d.jpg', u'c5.staticflickr.com/9/8313/29722500236_76d7bdbdd8.jpg', u'c8.staticflickr.com/9/8580/29776721935_f1ce85e967_n.jpg', u'c3.staticflickr.com/9/8364/29731556026_1f9d166845.jpg', u'c3.staticflickr.com/9/8178/29726200506_4439500c3d.jpg', u'c4.staticflickr.com/9/8405/29138108963_288aa48d06.jpg', u'c4.staticflickr.com/9/8565/29137949003_fb41535bd6.jpg', u'c5.staticflickr.com/9/8109/29735723636_0e494810a2.jpg', u'c3.staticflickr.com/9/8482/29662415042_5b0d05c8f3.jpg', u'c1.staticflickr.com/9/8346/29726788896_8c293fbdf7.jpg', u'c3.staticflickr.com/9/8524/29725439906_2b067f0212.jpg', u'c6.staticflickr.com/9/8303/29140293093_e355f8e8cd.jpg', u'c3.staticflickr.com/9/8011/29477607810_db00655d55.jpg', u'c1.staticflickr.com/9/8227/29465026920_36ab1c9637.jpg', u'c2.staticflickr.com/9/8014/29770085625_5163a499d1.jpg', u'c1.staticflickr.com/9/8090/29719718136_5f5ab26519.jpg', u'c1.staticflickr.com/9/8198/29645435472_f5284dedfd.jpg', u'c1.staticflickr.com/9/8692/29469829440_4481cea5e2.jpg', u'c4.staticflickr.com/9/8126/29142193643_f7a2100439.jpg', u'c3.staticflickr.com/9/8395/29646613162_8bbfcb4783.jpg', u'c1.staticflickr.com/9/8182/29482891560_66a7453201.jpg', u'c6.staticflickr.com/9/8078/29137768373_f8c8ebc474.jpg', u'c4.staticflickr.com/9/8142/29754486795_5517360b29.jpg', u'c1.staticflickr.com/9/8276/29138669944_c94fb64f7e.jpg', u'c7.staticflickr.com/9/8189/29658148142_44845e5842.jpg', u'c3.staticflickr.com/9/8168/29724488906_dd17d56015_n.jpg', u'c1.staticflickr.com/9/8450/29727877336_b9d852bc7b.jpg', u'c7.staticflickr.com/8/7471/29129926854_ceff45aaeb.jpg', u'c4.staticflickr.com/9/8298/29690071131_5a7589870d.jpg', u'c8.staticflickr.com/9/8003/29131670143_9cb629648a.jpg', u'c3.staticflickr.com/9/8022/29722826586_c07240a926_n.jpg', u'c3.staticflickr.com/9/8332/29663153602_c9364a94ac.jpg', u'c4.staticflickr.com/9/8219/29767151515_3c9c12d47a.jpg', u'c6.staticflickr.com/9/8475/29675880341_baa5c43403.jpg', u'c5.staticflickr.com/9/8246/29646906852_ff44a93f55_n.jpg', u'c2.staticflickr.com/9/8113/29141997673_64184d61fd_n.jpg', u'c7.staticflickr.com/9/8517/29131116894_1319f5a4af.jpg', u'c5.staticflickr.com/9/8169/29472205700_4930f81031_n.jpg', u'c3.staticflickr.com/9/8051/29466854090_804671e48d.jpg', u'c4.staticflickr.com/9/8459/29772050115_0d602920a9_n.jpg', u'c6.staticflickr.com/9/8413/29762049765_951f4c683c_n.jpg', u'c8.staticflickr.com/9/8480/29132401623_50619e22c5_n.jpg', u'c7.staticflickr.com/9/8410/29482793550_8b338c8432_z.jpg', u'c6.staticflickr.com/8/7501/29693717381_dd907ac02a.jpg']
```

Comment: Thanks. The book I'm following does not use re. Is it possible to achieve the same, using just what bs4 offers?

Comment: Unfortunately not, bs4 is a HTML parser it can only parse what it is given. If you want to get the source you see in your browser you will need to use something that can render the dynamic content like selenium.

Comment: I'm still getting nothing. This is what i have: urls = [url_re.search(d['style']).group(1) for d in soup.select('div.view.photo-list-view requiredToShowOnServer')]
print(urls)

Comment: I am. your suggested code is cut of at ...-list. So I provided the code (you suggested) in the comment, to see if its correct. (i did not include re.recompile)

Comment: Your code is not the same. Read the code carefully and you will see your select is not the same.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see it. Your .select is cut off. The .select I have is 'div.view.photo-list-view requiredToShowOnServer'. I changed .select to this: 'div.view.photo-list-view.requiredToShowOnServer', when I ran it, I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'. I then changed it to: 'view.photo-list-photo-view.requiredToShowOnServer awake' - no error but returned an empty list. What is in .select?

Comment: My select is not cut off, it is correct as posted. I added the code running from ipython where you can see it gets all the urls. `div.view.photo-list-view requiredToShowOnServer` is not a correct selector, it would be `div.view.photo-list-view.requiredToShowOnServer`, notice the `.requiredToShowOnServer`. You also don't need to be that specific, what is in my answer is fine.

Comment: import webbrowser, bs4, os, requests, sys, re
url_re = re.compile("url\(//(.*?)\)")
res=requests.get('https://www.flickr.com/photos/')
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
urls = [url_re.search(d["style"]).group(1) for d in soup.select('div.view.photo-list-view.requiredToShowOnServer')]                                                                                                             
print(urls)

Comment: I get an attribute error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'